# Is f the zero function?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am told to find the error in the following argument:

let $f(z)= \cdots + \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{z} + 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$

Note that $z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}$

and $1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^2} + \cdots = \frac{-z}{1-z}$

hence f(z) = 0

My argument is to point out that $z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{z}{1-z}$
only holds when |z| < 1 and $1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^2} + \cdots = \frac{-z}{1-z}$ can only hold in the region where 1 < |z|. Is this a sufficient counterargument or is there something else I am missing because this argument seems too simple.

thank you

Comment: It’s exactly what I would have said. The doubly-infinite series presented to you is nowhere convergent,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument actually is correct that $f(z)=0$ for all $z$ such that $f(z)$ is defined.  But, as you say, $f(z)$ is actually not defined for any $z$ at all, since there do not exist any $z$ such that the series defining $f(z)$ converges on both sides.  So, $f(z)=0$ is true for all $z$ such that $f(z)$ is defined, but this is a vacuous statement.

Comment: There is no point where both the series converge so $f(z)$ is not defined for any $z$.